# Postgresql with Npgsql "relation <tablename> does not exist." Only occurring on Win 7

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm running into a very strange bug when using Postgresql using the Npgsql (2.0.11 and 2.0.11.94) DLL in .NET 3.5.

I've created a program that will run these two queries (these are copied directly from the programs output):

```
INSERT INTO "db_events" VALUES ('2','1','2','1', to_timestamp('2012/08/27 10:22:43', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'2012', '8', '27', '10', '22', '43', '35' );

INSERT INTO "db_events_counts" VALUES ('1','2', '0', '1', '0', '1' );
```

This program will run perfectly fine on Windows XP x86 with both postgres 8.4.12 and 9.0.9, and will enter the data into the tables as it should.

However, when running the exact same program on Windows 7 with a database that has been set up in an identical way to the Windows XP data base, I run into the error:

```
ERROR: 42P01: relation "db_events" does not exist
```

I have read that this error is because postgres is forcing table names to lowercase, which is fine since they are already. Or that a table created with quotes has to be referenced with quotes, which is also fine since I am using quotes.

In the windows 7 database, if i copy and paste these two queries into pgadmin, they work fine, no errors, this leads me to believe it's something to do with the DLL?

What doesn't make sense is this program working bug free on my Windows XP system while throwing this error constantly on Windows 7.

I also try a simple delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM "db_events"; DELETE FROM "db_events_counts";
```

But that also ends in the same error.

Is there anything I am missing? 
Does Npgsql need to be compiled in the same windows environment as it's run in? 
or is there some subtle difference between windows 7 and windows XP with postgres that I am not getting.

Any help or information on the topic would be greatly appreciated.

---

Due to questions about the connection, here is what i have tried:

```
Server=localhost;Port=5433;User Id=databaseuser;Password=databaseuser_123;Database=db123;
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5433;User Id=databaseuser;Password=databaseuser_123;Database=db123;
Server=10.223.132.123;Port=5433;User Id=databaseuser;Password=databaseuser_123;Database=db123;
```

The last being the local machines IP address.

---

Here is a short log of the program connecting and disconnecting from the server on Win 7:
// connecting

```
2012-08-27 11:26:00 EST ERROR:  relation "db_events" does not exist at character 13
2012-08-27 11:26:00 EST STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM "db_events"; DELETE FROM "db_events_counts";
2012-08-27 12:52:29 EST ERROR:  relation "db_events" does not exist at character 13
2012-08-27 12:52:29 EST STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "db_events" VALUES ('114','1','2','1', to_timestamp('2012/08/27 12:52:29', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'2012', '8', '27', '12', '52', '29', '35' );
```

// disconnecting

```
2012-08-27 11:26:07 EST LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2012-08-27 11:26:07 EST LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

Comment: Are you absolutely, 100% certain it's really connecting to the correct database? This is *certainly* a local configuration issue of some sort; Pg really doesn't care what the platform is.

Comment: Its defiantly connecting to the right database, there is only one database on the whole machine and there are no connection errors, both environments are identical appart from the windows version (SQL scripts were used to set up both). However, if you can think of a reason it wouldn't be connecting to the right database I'd be glad to try and fix it.

Comment: If it were a libpq dll compatibility issue you'd likely be seeing crashes or truly wacky behaviour, not getting valid error messages from the database. If it were Npgsql, I'd expect to see exceptions that didn't have a server-side SQLSTATE in them.

Comment: Sure it's not connecting to a db on *another* machine?

Comment: Try adding some code to your program that runs the SQL statement: `SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relnamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'public');` . Print the results. Do you see the table you expect? Also try `SELECT current_database();` . The schema info functions may be useful: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-info.html . It can also be handy to turn server-side query logging on with `log_statement='all'` in `postgresql.conf` and reload/restart Pg, then examine the server logs.

Comment: @CraigRinger I ran both those scripts and the output is as I expected, unfortunatly. It does seem to be the right database.

Comment: Odd, the mystery deepens. It's the right DB, you've excluded case sensitivity issues. Your next step is to enable query logging in the database as shown above and watch what queries hit the database. Oh, also, make sure your `search_path` includes the schema with the table(s) of interest in it, presumably `public`; try `SHOW search_path` from npgsql.

Comment: @CraigRinger should I assume that `"$user",public` is the wrong answer from `SHOW search_path`? I could try a query such as `SET search_path TO db123, public;` however last time I tried that it complained that db123 didn't exist as a schema.

Comment: Well, that depends entirely on where your tables are. If they're in the `public` schema, then it's fine. Did you specify an explicit schema when creating them or set a `search_path` before creating them? If not, they're in the `public` schema. You can confirm by connecting with `psql` and running `\dt` ; you'll see the schemas the tables are listed in. Seriously, you need to enable log_statement then capture an *entire* session from when the app opens the connection to when it disconnects, including any `BEGIN`, `SET`, etc statements.

Comment: @CraigRinger sorry about that, I forgot to mention I've done that and put the output into the original question, every thing appears to be set up correctly, the two snippets are from the server log on the computer. Public schema is fine, thats where they should be judging from the other database.

Comment: @CraigRinger Found it, when I attempted to do `select * from public.db_events` I got a permission denied error (even though the user I am using is the owner of the database). Apparently the user has no read privileges, which meant he was not allowed to access anything within the public schema, the solution was to give him `superuser`, `can modify catelogue directly`, `can create database objects` and `can create roles`. You were a big help in this, I'd have never thought to try public.db_events and gotten the access denied error otherwise. Strange how none of that was printed in the server log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strange and erratic behaviour seen here, and discussion in the comments, suggests that the system catalogs (in the `pg_catalog` schema) may've been modified directly - perhaps an attempt to `REVOKE` some permissions.

That's not a good idea. The system catalogs should really only be modified by experts. That's one of the reasons only superuser accounts can modify them directly, and one of the many reasons you should not use superuser accounts in day-to-day operation.

Unless you know exactly what was done and can undo it, I'd recommend reverting to a working copy of the database like the one on your known-good XP machine. `GRANT`ing access to `public` in `pg_catalog` sounds like it helped, but who knows what else has been done.

If this were my DB I'd take a `pg_dump` of each database and a `pg_dumpall --globals-only` and restore it to a spare DB to make sure it looked complete. I'd then stop Pg and re-initdb. That's a bit of a pain on Windows, though, so you might well be fine with just backing up the damaged database, `DROP`ping it, re-creating it and restoring the data back into it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with the help of CraigRinger.

Even though the user I was logging in as was the owner of the database, he did not have permission to look into anything under the public schema.

This was discovered using:
`select * from public.db_events`

which, instead of throwing a `relation not found` error, threw an `access is denied` error.

After changing the user I was logging in as to a `superuser` and ticking all the check boxes under "role privileges", the `relation not found` error didn't occur any more.

Comment: Regular app users really shouldn't be superusers, and certainly shouldn't need to be. This is very weird. Furthermore, why `permission denied` when `npgsql` was reporting `does not exist` is odd. There's more to this than we've seen so far. I'm wondering if somebody's been mucking with the catalog directly? Personally I'd drop the whole cluster and re-initdb it.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm the only one who's got access to this machine, but following your advice I de-superusered the account and using the "Grant Wizard" gave all permissions to public for all objects. This allows my user to access everything, even without superuser. I'm beginning to think all this is just due to in-experiance unfortunatly, I'll have to do quite a bit of research on this.

Comment: Yeah, maybe if someone `REVOKE`d a bunch of permissions in `pg_catalog` you could see behaviour like this. Drop your cluster and re-initdb if you can easily restore it from a template (say, like a dump taken from the working XP machine). Who knows what's broken.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL folds all identifiers to lower-case. This is PostgreSQL behavior, and has nothing to do with Npgsql - the latter simply passes along your SQL as you wrote it. You can switch to all-lowercase table names, in which case you no longer need the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Table exists , if using some migration to create table then confirm it is being created before you do any operation on the table! Good luck

Comment: This question was answered a long time ago and this answer doesn't add anything, were you trying to answer a different question?